# Converting Historical Timestamps from UTC to Local

Tags: perl, utc

I have a file with timestamps that are in the past and are all in UTC. I need to convert these to Eastern Time. I've gotten close, but it messes up around the daylight savings changeover.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;

#DST not in effect
my $utc = '2015-03-08 01:59:00.000';
my $local = utc_to_local($utc);
print "DST not in effect: utc($utc) = local($local)\n";

#DST not in effect
$utc = '2015-03-08 02:00:00.000';
$local = utc_to_local($utc);
print "DST not in effect: utc($utc) = local($local)\n";


sub utc_to_local
{
    my $utc_ts = $_[0]; #this has ms on right side, we want left 19 characters
    $utc_ts = substr $utc_ts, 0, 19;
    my $local_tp = localtime->strptime( $utc_ts, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' );
    $local_tp = $local_tp + $local_tp->tzoffset();

    return $local_tp->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
}
```

As you can see, if I try 1:59 AM UTC on 3/8 and 2 AM UTC on 3/8, it thinks the change has occurred, but 2 AM UTC is only 3/7 at 9 PM. Away from the daylight savings changeover it does -5 and -4 offsets correctly.

```
DST not in effect: utc(2015-03-08 01:59:00.000) = local(2015-03-07 20:59:00)
DST not in effect: utc(2015-03-08 02:00:00.000) = local(2015-03-07 22:00:00)
```

Comment: The DST change happens at 2:00 a.m. Eastern time, not 2:00 a.m. UTC. The critical seconds are 2015-03-08 01:59:59 EST (UTC-05:00) == 2015-03-08 06:59:59 UTC followed by 2015-03-08 03:00:00 EDT (UTC-04:00) == 2015-03-08 07:00:00 UTC. Also, `localtime` uses the timezone you're currently in, which is not necessarily the timezone you *were* in.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Right, I understand why it's wrong, I just don't know how to fix it. And the second part isn't a concern here, the data is all generated in the eastern time zone, but a good point for a more general solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$utc_ts` isn't a local time.

```
my $local_tp = localtime->strptime( $utc_ts, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' );
```

should be

```
my $utc_tp = Time::Piece->strptime( $utc_ts, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' );
```

---

Then there's the issue of converting to localtime.

```
$local_tp = $local_tp + $local_tp->tzoffset();
```

should be

```
my $local_tp = localtime($utc_tp->epoch);
```

---

All together:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw( );
use Time::Piece;

sub utc_to_local {
    my ($utc_ts) = @_;
    my $utc_tp = Time::Piece->strptime( $utc_ts, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' );
    my $local_tp = localtime($utc_tp->epoch);
    return $local_tp->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
}

sub local_to_utc {
    my ($local_ts) = @_;
    my $local_tp = Time::Piece->strptime( $local_ts, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' );
    my $utc_tp = gmtime($local_tp->epoch);
    return $utc_tp->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
}

{
    $ENV{TZ} = 'America/Toronto';
    POSIX::tzset();

    # DST not in effect
    my $utc = '2015-03-08 06:59:00.000';
    my $local = utc_to_local(substr($utc, 0, -4));
    print "DST not in effect: utc($utc) = local($local)\n";

    # DST not in effect
    $utc = '2015-03-08 07:00:00.000';
    $local = utc_to_local(substr($utc, 0, -4));
    print "DST not in effect: utc($utc) = local($local)\n";
}
```

Output:

```
DST not in effect: utc(2015-03-08 06:59:00.000) = local(2015-03-08 01:59:00)
DST not in effect: utc(2015-03-08 07:00:00.000) = local(2015-03-08 03:00:00)
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked. It was using the seconds since epoch as a sort of universal translation that I wasn't thinking about.